# Changing file name while installing

Tags: wix, windows-installer

If I have `A.txt` as a components

Can I Install it as `B.txt` (different name, whatever) ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to add the Name="b.txt" into the 
`<File Id="testFile1" Name="testFile1.txt" Source="c:\TestFile1.txt" />`

Comment: I don't know why. First time I tried this way, it didn't work. But this time it works perfectly, Thanks !

Comment: So you would change it to this?
<File Id="AFile" Name="B.txt" Source="c:\A.txt" />

Comment: Yes you can try it

Comment: Awesome! Lifesaver.